# Java Array get digits and make number from array input

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, digits

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tar0 {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int d, i = 0, a = 0, f = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter How many Digits you want?");
        d = in.nextInt();
        int num[] = new int[d];
        for(i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Single Digit");
            num[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(i = d; i > 0; i--) {
            a = a + (num[i] * f);
            f = f * 10;
        }
        System.out.println("The Number is: " + a);
    }
}
```

**Question:** User will enter number of digits and the program will make from it a number I have wrote the code by myself but it doesnt seems to work.

When Running the program:

1. the input seems to work fine. I have tried to test the output of the
2. array without the second loop with the calculation, seems to work
   but with the calculation seems to crush:

   `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
       at tar0.main(tar0.java:17)`

What's the deal?

Comment: Java uses 0-based indexes. The valid indexes are 0..(d-1)

Comment: Please try to format your code properly before posting it here (actually, just always format your code properly, it will increase readability and make it easier to find bugs or understand what the code does). Also, try to follow naming convention (for instance: Class names should start with an uppercase letter, variables with lowercase letters).

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays start at 0 and continue up from there. The way your code is formatted right now you are losing a value and therefore your array is too small to hold the values. 
One option as outlined above would be to decrement your d value so that we are using a proper array size in the loop. This would be the preferred way so I removed the additional code above for the other option.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tar0 {
static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int d,i=0,a=0,f=1;
    System.out.println("Enter How many Digits you want?");
    d=in.nextInt();
    int num[] = new int[d];
    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Single Digit");
        num[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
    for(i =  d - 1; i >0 ; i--)
    {
        a=a+(num[i]*f);
        f=f*10;

    }
    System.out.println("The Number is: "+a);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified the following code it will work.

```
for(i=d;i>0;i--)
{
    a=a+(num[i-1]*f);
    f=f*10;

}
```

Array index value will start at 0. so change array from num[i] to num[i-1]